# Differents entry points with Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, entry-point

I want to have an structure like this

```
http://localhost:8080/

http://localhost:8080/problem2/

http://localhost:8080/problem3/
```

...

I also want a python structure like this

```
-src

    - app.yaml
    - main.py
    - package_problem_2
        - main.py
    - package_problem_3
        - main.py
```

I would like to have differents main.py for the differents folder in my web. 
I mean, if I am in `http://mydomain:8080` it is `src/main.py` the want that handle the requests. But, if I am in `http://localhost:8080/problem2` it should be `package_problem_2/main.py` the one which handle the requests.

Is this possible?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Yes it is doable, have a look at the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig). When you try something, come back & edit your question to show your tries (if you have any difficulties ofcourse, goodluck)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using webapp2 framework?

If so, read on...

You need four files.  For simplicity, all are located in the root folder of your app:

```
app.yaml
urls.py
SampleController.py
Sample.html
```

on your app.yaml, you should have something like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: urls.ap
```

That tells appengine to route all url patterns to urls.py.

Then on your urls.py, you have this structure:

```
import webapp2
import SampleController

#For each new url structure, add it to router.
#The structure is [py filename].[class name inside py file]
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(debug=True)
app.router.add((r'/', SampleController.SampleHandler))


def main():
    application.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

On your problem, you have three structures: /, /problem2, /problem3.  They would correspond to these:

```
app.router.add((r'/', SampleController.SampleHandler))
app.router.add((r'/problem2', SampleController.SampleHandler2))
app.router.add((r'/problem3', SampleController.SampleHandler3))
```

It's up to you to decide if they go to the same handler or not.

SampleController.py looks like this:

```
import webapp2
import os

class SampleHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'handler': 'We are in SampleHandler',
            'param2': param2 
        }
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Sample.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))


class SampleHandler2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'handler': 'We are in SampleHandler2',
            'param2': param2 
        }
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Sample.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))


class SampleHandler3(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {
            'handler': 'We are in SampleHandler3',
            'param2': param2 
        }
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Sample.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

Notice they all go to the same Sample.html file.

Sample.html is just standard html code.

Comment: It is not exactly what I want, because I would like to define in `SampleHandler2` (which is in another package, in a module know as `main.py`) all the possible redirection that this handler has. What I mean is, I'd like to define in that module this

    `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/problem2/', MainHandlerForProblem2),
                               ('/problem2/thanks',ThanksHandlerForProblem2)], debug=True)`

As it is in the main `main.py` in the "default" package